# How to position dropdown menu of bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know whether it is a bug or not, because I tried everything to adjust the position of bootstrap dropdown menu, but it doesn't seem to work

this is my code

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50px;
    background: #563c7c;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I want to make the dropdown menu  centered..
Sorry I cant provide an image because I can't.. not enough reputation

Any help would be highly appreciated thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (min-width:768px) {

  .dropdown-menu {
    left:-75px;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;        
  }

}
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/nukogi/1/edit**

[image]

You will need to play with this probably per dropdown depending on the width of the parent.

Comment: What would you need to do if you only wanted the adjustment to a specific dropdown-menu and not necessarily site wide?

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent div "dropdown"? make sure it has "position: relative" so that the child elements with "position: absolute" will be correctly displayed.